# Configuring dap-mode for debuggin remote server

Tags: java, debugging, emacs

I'm using Emacs with lsp-mode and dap-mode. 
This is the template:

```
     (dap-register-debug-template
   "localhost:8000"
   (list :type "java"
         :request "attach"
         :hostName "localhost"
         :port 8000))
```

I started the app I want to debugg with remote debugging (it works if I user Eclipse as debugger). It waits for the connection:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

When I use dap-debug and select the template, the new buffer stays black, and the app keeps waiting for connection.
[image]

I have also tried with the hostname, intead of localhost, but still not working. 
I'm using emacs 26 for windows.

I'm missing something??

Answer (score -1):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode/issues/67) indicating that dap-mode does not support `attach` requests for debugging remote Python processes as of 2021-03-26.